# How to get ConsoleFull Output,changeLog of upstream job along with downstream jobs console full output and changeLog in jenkins pipeline jobs!

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile, pipeline

Lets say we have Jobs A , B , C ,D and E.
Job A triggers Job B ;
Job B triggers Job C;
Job C triggers Job D;,
Job D triggers Job E;

When one of the child job fails for example: Job c fails then email should be sent to recipients of Job A ,Job B and Job c along with console output of A and changeLog ; Console output of Job B and changeLog and Console Output of Job C and changeLog all these info should be sent.!

Is there any way to do this ?
Need to use groovy script or how?

Comment: Sounds like you should just convert to a pipeline job.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can use

```
${BUILD_URL}/consoleText
```

or even better

```
$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/lastSuccessfulBuild/log
```

there is the log of the last successful build, the others are:

```
lastCompletedBuild
lastFailedBuild
lastStableBuild
lastUnstableBuild
lastUnsuccessfulBuild
```